# Run runnable by thread pool, should I use volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Like the example code like follows.

I'm going to using a thread pool to run the object of TestRunnable in period.

Should I declare the variable total as volatile?

```
public class TestRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int total;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (total > 10) {
            return;
        } else {
            total += 1;
            System.out.print("Run in times: " + total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the crucial point is: What are you actually **doing** with the `total` variable? If you are only using it internally (for the print statement), and if you submit each `TestRunnable` instance only *once* to the thread pool, then you don't need `volatile`. But **if** there is, for example, a `getTotal` method that exposes the variable in any way, then additional synchronization (or, in the simplest case, a `volatile`) may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fact, that your variable is declared as

```
 private int total;
```

(Not static)

It will not be shared between multiple threads (**As long as you keep creating new instance  for each submitted thread**), so there is no need to declare it as volatile.

If you do use the same instance multiple times - then you should consider using **AtomicInteger** instead of regular **int**, since operation

```
total+= 1;
```

or

```
total++;
```

Is not an atomic operation, which might lead to some unexpected results in *multithreaded env.*

Comment: Worth noting that _most_ of the time you don't really need to use volatile and want proper synchronization instead.  Or atomic types (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).  I think volatile is only useful when people who know what they are doing optimize things that are critical for performance.

Comment: @NathanHughes interesting.  Can you even submit the same instance to the same pool multiple times?  I never considered doing that.

Comment: This variable is not static, but I use a thread pool execute it.
So multi thread may access the variable.

Comment: @yunfan, as it was noted previously, if you create new instance of **TestRunnable** each time you submit it to your, lets say, executor, you will not suffer from these problems, but your code wont work as designed i guess (or will it?). If you do use the same instance of **TestRunnable** - it will share his state among all the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you would mark the field `volatile` it would be worth nothing since the `if` statement isn't atomic. Consider the following situation:

1. A thread executes `TestRunnable`'s `run()` method.
2. The expression `total > 10` evaluates to `false` because `total` is 10.
3. As a result, the thread enters the `else` branch and trys to increment the variable.
4. Another thread does the same, but `total` hasn't been incremented yet.
5. Now, both threads incremented `total`, which could leave it in an inconsistent state.

Note that this can only happen if you submit the same instance multiple times to your pool (at least that's the only situation I can think of). However, since you're managing state within that `Runnable`—which seems wrong to me—that's probably what you're doing.

As pointed out by [@DmitriyKotov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41347065/3429133), you should switch to an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). Since Java 8 you could easily do:

```
total.getAndUpdate(currentVal -> currentVal > 10 ? currentVal : currentVal + 1);
```